# How to refresh the DbContext with a Database first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

Problem: We have an application that is potentially a multi-user environment. Because of Entity's caching, we are unable to see another users changes in the database when/after it happens. I am not looking to continuously poll the database. I would be okay if the user could click a "Refresh" button and have the context grab the new information from the database.

Things of note:
-We are utilizing a cache with a decently long life-time, and would like to keep that. 
-Solely looking for a way to refresh the context with the latest values from the database.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I can provide a code sample upon request.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?: `Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload()` (reloads an entity from the database)

Comment: What do you mean with "unable to see another users changes in the database.." ?
Would this help you ?
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first#5-dealing-with-database-changes)

Comment: What's the lifetime of your DbContext usage? I.e. are you creating a new context per request/per query? Are you treating the context as a singleton that's shared across all requests?

Comment: It is accross all requests.

Comment: @ReRoute You have used my solution but marked another as correct answer!

Comment: I am using VS 2017, .Net Framework 4.5.2, and EF 4. There is no DataClasses1DataContext.Entry() method. My issue is getting a reload of the data in a LINQ query when I select a different entry in ListA to update ListB. I change a record in SSMS, click the entry that contains it in ListA, but ListB shows the same data before the change. Am I the only one that thinks Entity Framework is the spawn of the devil? That's a rhetorical question. What I'd like to know is, how do you refresh the contents of one class or multiple (the entire database) classes on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload a single entity from the database, you can do the following:

```
Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload()
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful, i ended up changing it up a little from this, however.
         `var test = _Database.ChangeTracker.Entries()
     .Where(entry => (entry.Entity as Class1) != null)
     .Where(entry => (entry.Entity as Class2) != null);

    foreach (var dbEntityEntry in test) {
     dbEntityEntry.Reload();
    }`

Comment: I am using VS 2017, .Net Framework 4.5.2, and EF 4. There is no DataClasses1DataContext.Entry<T>() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList()
            .ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Comment: I am using VS 2017, .Net Framework 4.5.2, and EF 4. There is no DataClasses1DataContext.ChangeTracker() method.